# Rails - New temp directory getting automatically created every time I run bundler command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I have generated a basic web app using Rails 4.1.4/Ember.js and everything works as expected, but every time I run 'bundle install' etc. it creates a new (empty) folder in my root directory of the form **'bundler20140904-22128-1jtt7b7'** (the random digits at the end change each time).  They pile up so deleting them is getting kind of annoying, but does anyone have any ideas why this could be happening??.  I couldn't find any info via Google, but I was consulting [this tutorial](http://blog.dcxn.com/2013/03/23/getting-started-with-ember-js-on-rails/) if that helps.  I'm running CentOS 6.5 with RVM and I have no idea which files are relevant but here's my **application.rb**:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module MyProject
  class Application < Rails::Application
  end
end
```

**config.ru**:

```
# This file is used by Rack-based servers to start the application.

require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
run Rails.application
```

**Gemfile**:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.4'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/ra
ils/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

#EMBER
gem 'ember-rails', git: 'git://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails.git'
```

If you need any more info please let me know.  I'd be grateful for any help you can provide!

Comment: What version of bundler are you using, `bundle --version`?

Comment: Also, what is the output of `bundle install --verbose`? (Maybe link this to a gist)

Comment: does it create a new 'bundle2014...' directory each time you run `bundle install`, or does it create just one?

Comment: @Davidann I'm using Bundler version 1.6.2, [--verbose output](https://gist.github.com/ericturnerdev/a4b30413339379410dd4).  It creates a new one each time so they accumulate unless I delete them.

Comment: What is the output of `bundle config`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey everyone thanks for the help. I ended up re-generating the app from scratch, and the problem went away. As far as what was causing this, it looks like for some reason the line:

`gem 'ember-rails', git: 'git://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails.git'`

in my Gemfile was causing problems.  I changed it to:

`gem 'ember-rails'`

and it was fixed.